# Show Workers Locations to Clients

Tags: javascript, geolocation, location, maps, coordinate

I want a way to to show our Clients a map with the current location of our employees on a map. I've tried to do this with Google Maps Coordinate, but it only gives 3 options for Roles (Admin, Dispatch, and Worker).

So, my Clients don't fit in any of those roles, since they are not assigned any Jobs, and don't need other controls (just be able to view locations.)

Is there any alternative to Google Maps Coordinate, which will allow me to show worker locations to my clients? or is it possible with Google Maps Coordinate API?

Answer (score 0):

I would suppose that the framework is not directly intended for the task you are thinking of. For me at least it looks that its simply used for managing mobile workers. i.e. you have your Admin's assigning location specific tasks, and then you have workers handling them.

So, if you want to use the framework for just monitoring some users locations without any additional communications needed, then I would suggest searching for other platform which would be build to suit that need.

In case you would want to use the coordinate still, then do check whether you could extract the location data of the workers, and then have your own map control in which you would then show your employees to your client. Or check whether the framework actually already supports having such a more limited views. Good starting point would be the [Help center](https://support.google.com/coordinate/).

Of course you could also make a simple application which sends coordinates & ID to the central server, and in server side you would then have a database storing the locations so they could be shown in a map. This approach would allow you to use other devices than the iOS & Android ones supported by the Google Coordinate.

Comment: thanks for the different suggestions. I found the answer, it's called HTML5 geolocation, duh! Get log/lat and plot it by Google Maps Javascript API.

Comment: Ok, I though that you needed to show more than just the location of the current device, anyway, if that was the original requirement, then I suppose that would indeed be easiest way on achieving the goal.